# Upload picture to Facebook by passing url in newUploadPhotoRequest

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

```
Request request = Request.newUploadPhotoRequest(Session.getActiveSession(),imageToBeUploaded,new Request.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    showPublishResult(getString(R.string.photo_post),response.getGraphObject(), response.getError());
                }
            });
```

ATM I am uploading to facebook by passing a bitmap.
But i have to upload photos from my website. So i download the image in AsyncTask and pass it here

Is there any method to upload via url using non depreciated methods ?

Comment: It really depends on what you're trying to do with your app. Do you really need to post (and host) the photo on Facebook? If you control the server side, then you can use open graph to share photos and get distribution that way. If you don't control the server side, then you can use the Feed Dialog to share links.

Answer (score 0):

There is no documented way of doing this that I know of, you could use https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/ (look at the Uploading Binary Data section) , and put in your url requests, but I think the best way is to download the file locally and post it as data , this way you can control the url content

Comment: Using batch will not help, you can't post to me/photos with a url.